# package androidx.databinding does not exist error

Tags: java, gradle, data-binding, androidx, android-studio-3.4

In my Java project, I'd like to migrate to the androidx package.
But there is some problem with the databinding.

I can't find any androidx.databinding library files

```
error: package androidx.databinding does not exist
```

My project gradle file is right here in `app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
```

in `gradle.properties`

```
# Apply androidX
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

whether if I removed `android.databinding.enableV2` or set it to `false`, the androidx.databinding not exist error is still there.

I was able to use databinding on Java quite well.
But I can't migrate to androidx because of the databinding issue.

How can I resolve this?

I use

- Android Studio 3.4
- Java
- Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4
- Gradle 4.5.1

Comment: androidx.databinding is not created, And when I opened DataBindingUtil class, it was in 'library-3.1.4-source.jar > android > databinding > DataBindingUtil" not androidx package

Comment: And I must to use gradle plugin version to 3.1.4 (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'), So I can't use Migrate to AndroidX manually.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the setup of your project

1. Check if kotlin-kapt plugin is applied in build.gradle for your project.
2. Check databinding compiler in build.gradle for your project.

that is,
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:"

currently latest version is 3.4.0 for databinding compiler library.